# Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function when calling safeTransferFrom function

Tags: web3js, abi, erc-721

I want to call the `safeTransferFrom` function to transfer ERC721 tokens. I am using the following code:

```
var contract = this.web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(contractabierc721)).at(contractAddress);
    // console.log(contract);
    var txdata =  contract.safeTransferFrom.call(from, to, 3, function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
    });
```

The `safeTransferFrom` signature is `from, to , tokenID`. However, when I call this way, it gives this error `Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function`.

What is the correct way to call this function?

I am using web3js version `^0.20.6`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that EIP 721 defines two function with the same name

- `function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) external payable;`
- `function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable;`

Web3 chooses the first one as default. To execute the other you have indicate the type of the parameters inside brackets. Like this:

```
contract.safeTransferFrom['address,address,uint256'](from, to, value, function (err, res) {
    console.log(err, res);
})`
```

With web3 v1.0 it is a similar but function name and parameters, see this for more details: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12.